# Azure cosmos db give escape character in RequestContinuation in c# code

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Here `token` and `maxItemCount` are parameters.

```
var feedOptions = new FeedOptions()
            {
                EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true,
                RequestContinuation = token,
                MaxItemCount = maxItemCount
            };

var query = client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(collection.SelfLink, feedOptions);
```

This above query is used below as `IQueryable<T>` query.

```
query.AsDocumentQuery().ExecuteNextAsync<T>());
return new Tuple<string, IEnumerable<T>>(page.ResponseContinuation, page);
```

Received Token with excape character string.

```
[{\"compositeToken\":{\"token\":null,\"range\":{\"min\":\"04A1E121212138\",\"max\":\"04A1121212B330\"}},\"orderByItems\":[{\"item\":\"2018-06-04T19:03:39\"}],\"rid\":\"s121212AD11OKwQ1212123==\",\"skipCount\":0,\"filter\":null}]
```

Thanks in advance.